# Predict the product (organic chemistry)

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I think that the first reaction would add into the ketone carbon, but I don't know where to go after that. 
A step-by-step explanation of the answer would be greatly appreciated!

[image: reaction]

---

Answer choices:

[image]

Comment: If the ketone is attacked, what is the intermediate result?

Comment: The second carbon would have an -OH group and an -OCH2CH3 group with everything else the same

Comment: Not quite, the oxygen would be negatively charged, balanced by the sodium (since we haven't added water yet). If you look at the possible results, this doesn't look good as the possible pathway. So what else is possible?

Comment: Would it involve something with the ester carbon?

Comment: The sodium ethanoate and ethanol would be suitable for a transesterfication (if there wasn't already an ethanol on the ester). So, when the benzyl chloride is added, the ethanol is displaced. Hold on a moment, I need to check something out. I thought I knew what was going to happen.

Comment: Actually, you are correct in that the ketone is attacked and the ethanol will be displaced by benzyl chloride to give a tertiary alcohol.

Comment: How does the benzyl chloride react? I thought it would be some sort of SN2 reaction, but this route doesn't seem consistent with the answer choices.

Comment: The rest of the workup removes a methyl group and reduces the alcohol, so the product is ???

Comment: I'm not certain what the process is, but when I looked for the reagents, it suggested that this (http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/w242306?lang=en&region=US) is a product.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: Look at http://www.chtf.stuba.sk/~szolcsanyi/education/files/Organicka%20chemia%20II/Prednaska%205_Aldehydy%20a%20ketony_Reakcie%20II/Doplnkove%20studijne%20materialy/Alkylation%20of%20enolates_Clayden.pdf. When the sodium ethanoate is added, the oxygen get a negative charge and a double bond is formed (with the inner carbon). CC(O-)=CC(=O)OCC

Comment: On the second page it states "A strong base can be chosen to deprotonate the starting material completely. There is complete
conversion of the starting material to the anion before addition of the electrophile, which is added
in a subsequent step" which is what we have.

Comment: Do you have access to a chemical drawing program? I can point you to one on the web. If you enter this SMILES, you will see the intermediate: CC(=O)C(C(=O)OCC)CC1=CC=CC=C1

Comment: Yes, I have chemdraw

Comment: Can I get the web reference from you? I can't figure out how to convert it in chemdraw without additional Excel downloads

Comment: Unfortunately, I had a problem with my computer and I don't have Chemdraw loaded so give me a moment and I'll load it.

Comment: We will need to use an online program since I didn't get the download yet. Goto https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search/substructure/SubstructureSearchPage  You will probably see a message from Java. If you get an error, click on Start, All Programs, Java, Configure Java: select the Security tab, Click Edit Site List, Add and enter https:/ /www.sigmaaldrich.com (without the space), click OK twice and reload the web page.

Comment: Okay, that works! So the first step would form an enolate ion that is resonance stabilized with the double bond of the ester. The double bond then attacks the benzyl chloride in an SN2 fashion. Next, does the base react with the ester?

Comment: Well, the final product is either C or E. I thought it might be E, but now I'm confused. Either the ethanol is removed to give a carboxylic acid, then CO2 is removed to give C, or CH3CO- (I don't know how) is removed to give E. So I am betting on C.

Comment: Folks, if you are going to discuss the possible answers, please make a chatroom instead of drawing out the comments section.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand that now. Thank you very much, LDC3! (Sorry, jonsca, will keep that in mind for next time.)

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a classic to me. But since this is homework, <strike>I will not provide a full reaction scheme</strike> and only give some hints.

1. Your starting material is a $\beta$-ketoester (1,3-dicarbonyl compound).

   - Where is the most CH-acidic position in this molecule?
   - Benzylchloride is an alkylating agent. What will happen when it reacts with the anion of your starting material?
   - For extra credit: Why is sodium ethoxide in ethanol a reasonable choice when you want to isolate, purify and characterize the product?
2. Your starting material did have an ester group. Does it still have it after the first step? If so, what will happen to it in aqueous alkaline solution?
3. (*This step would not work with the saponification product of a simple ester.*) 
   But you started with $\beta$-ketoester! Heating the product of step 2 in acidic media will let it loose some atoms. The mechanism may be drawn using a cyclic intermediate, in which the ketone has an assisting role.

---

**EDIT**
[image: beta-ketoester as synthon]

Deprotonation and subsequent benzylation of the $\beta$-ketoester occur at the most CH-acidic position, i.e beween the keto and the ester group. As a side note, benzylation at the methyl group adjacent to the carbonyl group is possible when using 2 equivalents of a strong base.

Using ethoxide rather than methoxide as a base makes sure that transesterification does not lead to a mixture of products.

The resulting benzylated $\beta$-ketoester is cleaved under alkaline conditions to the corresponding carboxylate. Under acidic conditions, this from a $\beta$-ketoacid.

Upon heating, $\beta$-ketoacids undergo decarboxylation (= they loose $\ce{CO2}$) to form an enolate which tautomerizes to the final methyl ketone.